# Can I demand the return of cores to my vassal?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Since the patch that came with the Art of War expansion, it is possible to start wars to reconquest core provinces from enemies that belong to your vassal.

However, when I finally win and capture those provinces, I have no option to return those provinces to my vassal. Instead I can only annex them myself. I can sell them to my vassal afterwards, but I get unnecessary AE this way for provinces I never wanted for myself in the first place.

Is there a way to return those core provinces directly to my vassal in peace negotiations? If yes, under which conditions will this option show up?

Comment: Is there anything under the "Return Cores" tab?

Comment: Nope, that's where I would've expected it too. There is nothing in any tab, that's the problem.

Comment: Think you could upload your save somewhere so I can hack around with it?

Comment: @Foosh: Nope, it's an ironman save and I already sold them back to my vassal. Are you saying this works for you?

Comment: I tried a month ago and it worked fine.  I was Muscovy, with Golden Horde as my vassal, and made Crimea return cores to them.  The difference was that this was a war of conquest rather than reconquest of cores, not sure of the wargoal plays a part.

Comment: In my game, I experienced something similar. Turns out, that my vassal had claims, but not actually cores. That might be one reason.

Comment: @Nix You can even give them claims in the peace treaty, just make sure they actually are the ones occupying the province.

Comment: Just to make sure - you DID try to transfer occupation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your vassal actually needs to control a province so that you can demand its return to him in the peace treaty.

When you are in control of the province, it's possible to pass the control on to your vassal in the province dialogue. Note that this only works if you have the Art of War DLC.